# What is the pdf of $X/Y$, where $X$ has a symmetrical uniform distribution, and $Y$ is normal with mean zero?

Tags: probability-distributions

If X has a uniform distribution, between some -L and L, and Y has a normal distribution, with zero mean and variance=Sigma^2.

The distribution of Q=Y/X is called the "Slash distribution". 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_distribution

How to obtain the distribution of Z=X/Y?

Thanks!

Comment: People, what's the point in down-grading my question if you don't explain why? What do we learn from this?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but your question could do with some additional comments, explaining your own attempts at solving your question, and where you got stuck. Also, the question doesn't really seem 'research-level' to me...

Comment: Since $Z = 1/Q$, you can transform the known distribution of one to get the other.

Comment: You should mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know $Y/X$ has pdf $f(q):=\frac{\varphi(0)-\varphi(q)}{q^2},\,\varphi(t):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{t^2}{2}$. Thus $Z:=\frac{1}{Q}$ has pdf $\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})=\varphi(0)-\varphi(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(1-\exp-\frac{1}{2z^2}\right)$.